# How can we achieve this in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

We want to send transactional data through Apacke Kafka as we are having two downstream systems and before we show success message in the UI we want to be sure that the data is saved successfully in both the downstream systems.

We are pushing the data through producer and reading it at the consumer end and able to save it in downstream systems. The missing link is how to know if the data was saved successfully in the down stream systems so that we can show success message on the UI.

Is there a way we can achieve it through Kafka. We have just started using kafka and not sure if this use case will fit kafka or not.

Comment: This use case will not fit kafka IMO. What is the reason behind using kafka in this scenario? There is no guarantee that the consumer will consume as soon as the message is pushed to the topic. So you don't want the UI to be responsive based on this message consumption.

Answer (score 0):

If your producer knows the consumers, it can observe the committed consumer offsets to see which records got consumed. The producer can map those offsets to the messages it did write itself.

For further details how to do this (way beyond the scope of a single question), just dig through the Kafka code (it's open source). As a starting point, look into `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` which is a tool to monitor consumer offsets.